How can I modify a surface to satisfy two distance conditions?
I have two variables, $\phi$ and $\theta$, and I'm trying to create a smooth surface such that the following rules are met for the distance between on the surface, $D$
\begin{align*}
1)& \: D[(\phi,\theta),(\phi+2\pi k,\theta)] = 0 \:\text{for}\: k=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,...\\
2)& \: D[(\phi,\theta),(\phi,\theta+2\pi k)] = 0 \:\text{for}\: k=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,...\\
3)& \: D[(\phi_1,\pi),(\phi_2,\pi)] = 0 \:\text{for arbitrary}\:\phi_1,\phi_2\\
4)& \: L[(0,0),(2\pi,0)] = L[(\phi,0),(\phi,2\pi)]
\end{align*}
Here, $L$ is the path length as traced along the curve from $0$ to $2\pi$. The only two surfaces with "nice" periodic structures, to my knowledge, are spheres and tori. However, it's very clear that a sphere does not meet these conditions, however, a torus of certain parameterization almost meets them. The parametric formula for a particular torus is
$$
\left(\left(1+\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)\cos\left(\phi\right),\left(1+\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)\sin\left(\phi\right),\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)
$$
which satisfies all the conditions except the last condition. Is there a way to construct a different surface perhaps embedded in 4D that allows for the fourth condition to be satisfied? I realize that this perhaps could be tiptoeing into the realm of impossible, but I'm not familiar enough with differential geometry to know.

If I'm reading right, condition 1 with $\phi = \theta=0$ (and $k=1$) says the left-hand side of 4 is $0$, while condition 2 with $\theta=0$ (and $k=1$) says the right-hand side is also $0$...?

@AndrewD.Hwang I made a mistake, the last point is meant to be the path length. Correcting it now

Thanks! A suitable reparametrization of your spindle torus works; it suffices to keep $\theta = \pi$ at the center and to move $\theta = 0$ to the top or bottom circle. Or do the coordinate curves need to have constant speed...?

Ideally, yes they should but it's dependent on if it's possible.

One more quick question: The post mentions smooth, but also requires  one coordinate curve to collapse to a point. Is infinitely differentiable, and an embedding except along $\theta = \pi$ enough? (Guessing "yes" since the spindle torus is mentioned.)

tl; dr: Infinite-dimensional families of surfaces of rotation in Euclidean three-space satisfying all four conditions exist, even if we restrict the coordinate curves to have constant speed. Intuitively, squeeze the spindle torus to make the "outer waist" have circumference $2\pi$ while preserving the arc length of the longitudinal sections.
In four-space, we can in addition ensure the longitudinal sections are circles.
Alternatively, in three-space we can reparametrize $\theta$ in the spindle torus so that $\theta = 0$ is one of the latitudes of circumference $2\pi$. (We can even do this by a real Möbius transformation acting on a circle.) The trade-off is we lose "constant-speed" in the $\theta$-coordinate curves.

In three-space: Fix a smooth, unit-speed plane curve $\bigl(u(\theta), v(\theta)\bigr)$ of length $2\pi$ that lies in the vertical strip $0 \leq u \leq 1$, touches the line $u = 0$ precisely where $\theta = \pi$, and touches the line $u = 1$ where $\theta = 0$. (For example, we can choose an ellipse of width $1$ and whose height makes the arc length $2\pi$. Particularly, we can ensure our parametrization is real-analytic.) The surface of rotation
$$
D(\phi, \theta) = \bigl(u(\theta)\cos\phi, u(\theta)\sin\phi, v(\theta)\bigr)
$$
satisfies the periodicity conditions 1 and 2, as well as the "collapsing at $\theta = \pi$" condition 3. Since $u(0) = 1$, the coordinate curve $\theta = 0$ has length $2\pi$, as does each longitudinal slice $\phi = \text{constant}$.
<>
No such surface in three-space has circular longitudinal cross sections (unless we allow a sphere "covered twice," which context rules out). We can, however, get circular cross sections in four-space. For example, fix non-zero real numbers $a$ and $b$ satisfying $a^{2} + b^{2} = 1$. The "spindle torus"
$$
D(\phi, \theta) = \bigl(a(1 + \cos\theta)\cos\phi, a(1 + \cos\theta)\sin\phi, b\cos\theta, \sin\theta\bigr)
$$
[sic: a factor of $b$ in the third component and not in the fourth] satisfies the periodicity conditions 1 and 2, as well as the "collapsing at $\theta = \pi$" condition 3. The partials are
\begin{align*}
D_{\phi} &= a(1 + \cos\theta)(-\sin\phi, \cos\phi, 0, 0),
& |D_{\phi}| &= a(1 + \cos\theta); \\
D_{\theta} &= (-a\sin\theta\cos\phi, -a\sin\theta\sin\phi, -b\sin\theta, \cos\theta),
& |D_{\theta}| &= 1.
\end{align*}
Consequently, the $\theta$-coordinate curves $D(\theta, \cdot)$ have constant speed $a(1 + \cos\theta)$, and the $\phi$-coordinate curves $D(\cdot, \phi)$ have unit speed.
Particularly, the curve $\theta = 0$ has length $2\pi a$ and the curves $\phi = \text{constant}$ all have length $2\pi$. Choosing $a = \frac{1}{2}$ and $b = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ gives a parametrization satisfying the "equal-length" condition 4.
